# Log In & Log Out Code In Header

Tags: wp-login-form

I have been searching for hours. I need a code that allows me to display a Login & Register link and when logged in display the users avatar along with name and logout button.

I'm not exactly great at writing php or putting them together, although I am still learning. Can anyone help me with this issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if(is_user_logged_in() ) {
      global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();
   echo get_avatar($current_user->user_email);
    echo 'Hello, '. $current_user->display_name;
   echo '<a href="/wp-login.php?action=logout">logout</a>';
} else {
     echo '<a href="/wp-login.php?action=login">login</a>';
     echo '<a href="/wp-login.php?action=register">register</a>';
}
```

Comment: @user32447 please accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet checks if the user is logged in. Depending on this, it either echos and displays a login or a logout link. If the user is logged in, it adds an avatar, followed by the users `display_name` before the link.

```
is_user_logged_in() 
    AND printf(
        '%s %s <a href="%s" alt="Logout">Logout</a>',
        get_avatar( get_current_user_id() ),
        get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'display_name' )
        wp_logout_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )
    );

wp_loginout( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

Keep in mind that you want to use the API functions so URls are filterable and get escaped server side. Example of the filter inside `wp_loginout()`:

```
apply_filters( 'loginout', $link );
```

So if plugins want to hook in, it fully is supported by above code.

Comment: Where to put "apply_filters( 'loginout', $link );" in order to change URL in a plugin form?

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz Put it into a custom plugin (a single file in plugins dir).